# Autofac object lifetime based on an event

Tags: c#, event-handling, inversion-of-control, autofac

Consider below code in ASP.NET Core

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddMvc();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        var loader = new LoadEngine<IContract>(@"DIRECTORY PATH") // works based on FileSystemWatcher and have ConcurrentDictionary as repository so can return latest types.
            .EnableHotPlug()
            .Build();

        var type = loader.GetInstances().FirstOrDefault().GetType(); // First Time
        builder.RegisterType(type).As<IContract>(); // First RegisterType

        loader.OnChange += () => // LoadEngine detect some changes in plugin directory so fire OnChange
        {
            type = loader.GetInstances().FirstOrDefault().GetType(); // Get latest instance from LoadEngine
            builder.RegisterType(type).As<IContract>(); // Register again in Autofac Container
        };

        builder.Populate(services);
        var container = this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
    }
```

I wrote a LoadEngine based on FileSystemWatcher when a plugin (.dll) created/deleted/updated in that directory reload types into memory and provide new instance so this library have OnChange event

I want to have instance`s life-scope based on an event when event call Autofac reinstantiation that object.

Now first Resigter type is OK but on event despite of existing a new type Autofac send old type to controllers

Comment: It's a bit tough to see what you're trying to do since your resolution code doesn't hold a reference. Is this a [startable service](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html)? That is, you just want one to be resolved for initialization purposes? `IsRegisteredWithKey` returns a Boolean - why is that being called? Do you want to change what's in the container or are you just trying to run some code when things change?

Comment: Note you should [treat a container as immutable](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/index.html#consider-a-container-as-immutable), so if you're trying to change what's in the container at runtime, consider a different design. [This discussion may help you.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811) In the meantime, perhaps cleaning up the code a bit and being more explicit about what you're trying to do would help. (Also, it's "Autofac" not "Autoface" - some cleanup on the text might help, too.)

Comment: @TravisIllig , This is just a try, I have a load engine that load assemblies from a directory when an assembly changed my load engine reload it so I need container recreate object so I need create a new object when change event called. I need life time of an object based on change event Is it possible ?

Comment: As mentioned, looking at your code it isn't clear what is happening so I can't answer your question. You're resolving a thing but not storing it? You're checking to see if it's registered for... No reason? I vaguely understand you have some assemblies you load but not whether the thing you're resolving is a singleton or what it's doing. At this stage all I can say is "Don't do this because it's changing the contents of the container" (read the docs I linked) but I can't be sure if I can say much else because _the question isn't clear._